# QLPreviewController not displays saved file

Tags: ios, objective-c, quicklook, qlpreviewcontroller

I'm getting this behaviour using `Xcode 8.0`. The problem is, after downloading a file and storing it on documents directory (code provided below), `QLPreviewController` only displays document's name and size. The property *currentPreviewItem* returns the correct path document. What's even more strange, is that if I try to open that document from another controller in my app, it works fine. I've implemented both *QLPreviewControllerDelegate* and *QLPreviewControllerDataSource*.

Code for downloading and saving document:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:file[@"url"]];

    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    if (!data) {
        completion([NSError new]);
        return;
    }

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *path = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:AppName];
    path = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:file[@"name"]];

    file[@"filePath"] = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:path contents:data attributes:nil];
        completion(nil);
    });
});
```

Then, when user selects a document I use the content saved on *@"filePath"* to show `QLPreviewController`. I've tried pushing it and presenting it modally and in both cases it just displays a gray page with document's name and size.

Comment: Could you upload your project to github? and so I can know the detail,thanks.

Comment: @QQ726535609 Hello, I can't share the project because it's not personal. However, if you can tell me which information you need I'll provide it to you. Thanks!

Comment: If you're sure that the contents downloaded are valid, you should probably file a radar on bugreport.apple.com

Comment: What is the file's extension?

Comment: @ThomasDeniau apparently that was the problem. Some of downloaded files don't include their extension in filename, so QLViewController can't open the file. If I add manually the extension, the file is shown correctly.

Answer (score 0):

File wasn't showed because downloaded contents didn't contain file's extension. When I tried opening it in other controller, it worked because I temporary used another file name containing the correct extension. So I solved the problem adding the extension .pdf to downloaded files that didn't include it. This made QLViewController displaying correctly the file.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, a file was created with the correct name, but the file contained an error message from the server, thus not representing the expected file structure.